# Pasar argumentos para modificar los títulos en un facet_wrap

Tags: label, facet-wrap

Estoy tratando de conseguir que un geom_point facetado por 'naves' (4*8) coloque las etiquetas en una sola línea usando 'labeller'

```
facet_wrap(~NAVE+variedad, nrow = 4, ncol = 8, labeller = label_context)
```

No sé cómo introducir el argumento multi_line = FALSE, lo haga como lo haga siempre me da error.

Por ejemplo:

> facet_wrap(~NAVE+variedad, nrow = 4, ncol = 8, labeller = label_context(multi_line = FALSE)) : Error in label_context(multi_line = FALSE) :
> argument "labels" is missing, with no default.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Sólo llevo tres meses usando R/ggplot2 y aún desconozco muchas cosas.
Gracias

Comment: Hola, de nuevo. Tras dos días de búsqueda he encontrado una solución. La copio aquí por si pudiera ser de utilidad para alguien. Las tres variables incluidas en el facetado responden a un mismo tipo de datos del facetado básico, que es por nave. Las otras dos variables ('variedad' e 'historia') tan solo añaden información complementaria de cada nave, no modifican el número de 'facetas' ni la asignación de datos. Copio el nuevo código: facet_wrap(~NAVE+variedad+historia, nrow = 4, ncol = 8, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 25, multi_line = FALSE))